# Memory Corruption in C linked list

Tags: c, linux, debugging, memory, memory-leaks

My program after running for around few hours randomly crashes because of a segmentation fault. My environment is Ubuntu (Linux)

When I try to print the data structure thats being accessed when it crashed the pointer is always pointing to invalid memory.

```
(gdb) p *xxx_info[8]
**Cannot access memory at address 0x7fd200000000**
(gdb)
```

In order to detect data corruption I add two fence variables that were hardcoded with a well defined value so that I can detect a memory corruption. I see that my fence variables for the linked list node which caused my process to crash had been violated from my earlier logs.

```
(gdb) p xxx_info
 $2 = {0x7fd248000c30, 0x7fd248001050, 0x7fd248000b30, 0x7fd248000d40, 0x7fd248000f50, 0x0,       
      0x7fd248001160, 0x7fd248001280, 0x7fd200000000, 0x7fd2480008c0, 
      0x7fd248003000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}
 (gdb) p xxx_info[8]
 $3 = (xxx_info_t *) 0x7fd200000000
 (gdb) p *xxx_info[8]
  **Cannot access memory at address 0x7fd200000000**
 (gdb)
```

I added the two fence variables at the start and the end of the data structures.

```
 (gdb) pt xxx_info_t 
 type = struct xxx_info_t {
   uint32_t begin_fence;
   char *str;
   int cluster_id;
   uint32_t end_fence;
 }
```

Under normal circumstances the fence variables MUST always be 0xdeaddead as shown below:

```
(gdb) p/x *xxx_info[7]
 $4 = {**begin_fence= 0xdeaddead**, str= 0x7fd248002f10, cluster_id= 0x1f2, **end_fence= 0xdeaddead**}
(gdb)
```

Whenever I access the array of pointers xxx_info I check for the fence values for each index. I noticed that I would get error messages saying that the fence variables for index 8 look corrupted. Later the code crashed when accessing index 8.

This means that somewhere I am overwriting the memory address pointed to by the index 8 of the array xxx_info .

My question is:

How can I debug these errors? Can I dynamically set some breakpoints so that whenever somebody overwrites that memory address I complain and assert. If this were a global variable that somebody were corrupting I could have set a HW breakpoint. Since this is a list created on heap (i malloc) the addresses that I will get will be dynamic and hence I can't use memory breakpoints/watchpoints.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Have you ran your code with valgrind?

Comment: It looks like your array was corrupted, not your data structure.  The problem is that you have a bad pointer in your array, not that the pointer is pointing at a corrupted structure.  Maybe you should look at how the array elements are assigned.

Comment: No Valgrind yet. @JS1 - Yes the array pointer is corrupted. But i see that even the element that it points to gets corrupted. I see  a print that says that my fence was violated.

Comment: Ok I see you said that your logs caught the data getting corrupted.  If you are logging all this, couldn't you stop your program as soon as your log detected that your fence was corrupted?  If you set a breakpoint for when you first detect the corruption, you might be able to reason out what just happened to corrupt your data structures.

Comment: One thing you could do is create a function `corruption_check()` that checks all your data structures for corruption and goes into an infinite loop if corruption is detected.  Then call that function from as many places you can in your code without slowing your program down too much.